# Only types 1 letter at a time

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, text-input

My girlfriend just bought a New Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGS3), everything is good however, when she tries to type something into a field box on the internet, it only types one letter at a time Eg:

Signing into hotmail, when typing in her email address you can only input one letter at a time, so as u press a letter it does not appear in the box but in predictive text, if you press on the completed word in predictive text it will only put the 1st letter in the box!!!

I also have a SGS3 but mine is fine, I can input my whole email address and each letter appears in the box after I press it on my phone. I have checked both out keyboard settings and they are identical. However, my keyboard has different keys on it when I go to type in the box, mine has the @ symbol and .com next to the space bar, hers does not.

Please help as this is frustrating us both!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too for a long time but have found that the key to stopping this glitch is to turn off the predictive text option in the keyboard settings every time you experience the 1st character input only problem. Personally, I like the predictive text being on 99% of the time, but some web pages (email providers mainly) aren't configured for predictive text to be used, so I keep predictive text on & just turn it off whenever I come across a web page where I experience the 1st character input only problem. To turn it on/off simply hit the cog button on the keyboard & where it says predictive text, just swipe the slider to the left, to the off position. This will allow whole words to be typed instead of just 1 character at a time. Then, once you've finished typing, you can hit the cog again & turn predictive text back on.